# how can i remove the ordering from a xsd sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

how can i remove the ordering restriction in the following xsd:

```
<xs:element name="example">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="hostname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="filename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="chunks" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbonded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

so at the end the following xml should be validated

```
<example>
    <chunks>...</chunks>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <chunks>...</chunks>
</example>
<!--  -->
<example>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <chunks>...</chunks>
    <chunks>...</chunks>
</example>
<!--  -->
<example>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <chunks>...</chunks>
    <chunks>...</chunks>
    <hostname>...</hostname>
</example>
```

---

accepted solution:

```
<xs:element name="example">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="hostname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="filename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="chunks" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbonded"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Can you place your `chunks` inside a `chunks-group` element? If you can, you could use `xs:all` (it's actually better design to keep similar repeating elements together (either by wrapping or sequence), so validating your code as is will not lead to a simple XSD)

Comment: in the first example this would be possible, but i've added another example

Comment: Just a remark: your solution is valid in XSD 1.1 only (in XSD 1.0 it's illegal to have `unbounded` elements in `xs:all`). This is important to mention, since XSD 1.1 is quite recent and not widely supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* achieve that with a combination of `sequence` and `choice` repeating the elements in the several possible combinations, to guarantee that the required ones are present, but it won't be so nice and simple. I would suggest a different design (if possible).

Is there any reason your `<chunks>` elements can appear anywhere? If you are designing the XML, deciding upon which restrictions are actually necessary and which ones should be made flexible will simplify generation and processing (as well as validation). Keeping them in a sequence or wrapping them will allow them to be seen as a `group` and will make validation easier (it would also simplify language mapping, for example, wrapped identical elements are frequently mapped as an array).

One form of keeping the similar elements together is `sequence`, which you don't want. Another would be to wrap it in a type and use `xs:all`:

```
<xs:element name="example">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="filename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="hostname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="chunks" type="ChunksType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="ChunksType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="chunk" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This would validate a XML fragment like this:

```
<example>
    <chunks>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
    </chunks>
    <filename>...</filename>
</example>
<!--  -->
<example>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <chunks>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
    </chunks>
</example>
<!--  -->
<example>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <chunks>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
    </chunks>
    <hostname>...</hostname>
</example>
<example>
    <hostname>...</hostname>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <chunks>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
    </chunks>
</example>
```

And fail for these:

```
<!-- missing filename -->
<example>
    <chunks>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
        <chunk>...</chunk>
    </chunks>
</example>

<!-- no chunks block -->
<example>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <hostname>...</hostname>
</example>

<!-- empty chunks block -->
<example>
    <hostname>...</hostname>
    <filename>...</filename>
    <chunks></chunks>
</example>
```

You can't just place your `unbounded` element in `xs:all` since it only allows `0` or `1`. You can't use a sequence of choices because you have required elements. And you can't combine `xs:all` with `sequence` which would solve your problem (actually you *can* do some of these things, but if you are using XSD 1.1).

In **XSD 1.1** you *can* have `xs:all` with `unbounded` elements so you could validate your XML using:

```
<xs:all>
    <xs:element name="filename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="hostname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="chunks" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:all>
```

which would be illegal in XSD 1.0.